# SyntaxError: invalid syntax re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'

Tags: python, django

Can't seem to resolve this syntax error... need help. Much appreciated.

The error:

```
  File "/max/home/urls.py", line 9
    re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home.views import HomeView
from . import views

app_name='home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
    re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
]
```

Comment: You are missing a `,` on the preceding line.

Comment: Wow haha it's been a long day!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put comma after `path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')`

Comment: Marking this answer as right...thank you...can't believe I couldn't see that ha!